# Вывести определенный товар Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет! Как вывести определенный товар с его полным описанием на странице, используя php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно просто создать инстанс класса `WC_Product` и передать туда ID текущего продукта:

```
$product = new WC_Product( 777 );
echo $product->get_name();
```

Подробнее в документации: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

Comment: Спасибо! А можно какой то пример?)

Comment: $product->get_description(); - вывод полного описания

Comment: Осознал, спасибо!